# Dynamically Flatten JSON response from API gives one Huge row

Tags: json, python-3.x, group-by

I am trying to dynamically flatten a json response for an API request but getting only one row with all the record back. kindly assist or point me in the right direction.

My json response looks like this

import requests, json
URL='https://data.calgary.ca/resource/848s-4m4z.json'
data = json.loads(requests.get(URL).text)
data

```
[{'sector': 'NORTH',
  'community_name': 'THORNCLIFFE',
  'group_category': 'Crime',
  'category': 'Theft FROM Vehicle',
  'count': '9',
  'resident_count': '8474',
  'date': '2018-03-01T12:00:00.000',
  'year': '2018',
  'month': 'MAR',
  'id': '2018-MAR-THORNCLIFFE-Theft FROM Vehicle-9',
  'geocoded_column': {'latitude': '51.103099554741',
   'longitude': '-114.068779421169',
   'human_address': '{"address": "", "city": "", "state": "", "zip": ""}'},
  ':@computed_region_4a3i_ccfj': '2',
  ':@computed_region_p8tp_5dkv': '4',
  ':@computed_region_4b54_tmc4': '2',
  ':@computed_region_kxmf_bzkv': '192'},
 {'sector': 'SOUTH',
  'community_name': 'WOODBINE',
  'group_category': 'Crime',
  'category': 'Theft FROM Vehicle',
  'count': '3',
  'resident_count': '8866',
  'date': '2019-11-01T00:00:00.000',
  'year': '2019',
  'month': 'NOV',
  'id': '2019-NOV-WOODBINE-Theft FROM Vehicle-3',
  'geocoded_column': {'latitude': '50.939610852207664',
   'longitude': '-114.12962865374453',
   'human_address': '{"address": "", "city": "", "state": "", "zip": ""}'},
  ':@computed_region_4a3i_ccfj': '1',
  ':@computed_region_p8tp_5dkv': '6',
  ':@computed_region_4b54_tmc4': '5',
  ':@computed_region_kxmf_bzkv': '43'}
]


Here is my code


``
`# Function for flattening
# json
 
 
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
 
    def flatten(x, name=''):
 
        # If the Nested key-value
        # pair is of dict type
        if type(x) is dict:
 
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
 
        # If the Nested key-value
        # pair is of list type
        elif type(x) is list:
 
            i = 0
 
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
 
    flatten(y)
    return out
 
 
# Driver code
# print(flatten_json(data))
newf=flatten_json(data)

pd.json_normalize(newf)`
``


It returns 

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6mUe.png)

While am expecting the data in the following format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXNtU.png).
```

json_normalize gives me the data in expected format but I need a way to dynamically parse different json request format (programmatically).

Comment: Hi gabidoye, welcome to Stackoverflow. If pandas json_normalize gives you result you want but your JSON looks different in real problem, it might be hard for us to help you as your problem is not reproducible. If you can, please post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your dataframe in correct form you can use this example (`data` is your list from the question):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

url = "https://data.calgary.ca/resource/848s-4m4z.json"

df = pd.DataFrame(requests.get(url).json())
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.pop("geocoded_column")
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .add_prefix("geocoded_column_"),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

df["geocoded_column_human_address"] = df["geocoded_column_human_address"].apply(
    literal_eval
)

df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.pop("geocoded_column_human_address")
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .add_prefix("addr_"),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| sector | community_name | group_category | category | count | resident_count | date | year | month | id | :@computed_region_4a3i_ccfj | :@computed_region_p8tp_5dkv | :@computed_region_4b54_tmc4 | :@computed_region_kxmf_bzkv | geocoded_column_latitude | geocoded_column_longitude | addr_address | addr_city | addr_state | addr_zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NORTH | THORNCLIFFE | Crime | Theft FROM Vehicle | 9 | 8474 | 2018-03-01T12:00:00.000 | 2018 | MAR | 2018-MAR-THORNCLIFFE-Theft FROM Vehicle-9 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 192 | 51.1031 | -114.069 |  |  |  |  |
| SOUTH | WOODBINE | Crime | Theft FROM Vehicle | 3 | 8866 | 2019-11-01T00:00:00.000 | 2019 | NOV | 2019-NOV-WOODBINE-Theft FROM Vehicle-3 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 43 | 50.9396 | -114.13 |  |  |  |  |
| SOUTH | WILLOW PARK | Crime | Theft FROM Vehicle | 4 | 5328 | 2019-11-01T00:00:00.000 | 2019 | NOV | 2019-NOV-WILLOW PARK-Theft FROM Vehicle-4 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 89 | 50.9566 | -114.056 |  |  |  |  |
| SOUTH | WILLOW PARK | Crime | Commercial Robbery | 1 | 5328 | 2019-11-01T00:00:00.000 | 2019 | NOV | 2019-NOV-WILLOW PARK-Commercial Robbery-1 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 89 | 50.9566 | -114.056 |  |  |  |  |
| WEST | LINCOLN PARK | Crime | Commercial Break & Enter | 5 | 2617 | 2019-11-01T00:00:00.000 | 2019 | NOV | 2019-NOV-LINCOLN PARK-Commercial Break & Enter-5 | 1 | 2 | 8 | 42 | 51.0101 | -114.13 |  |  |  |  |

Comment: thank @Andrej Kesey, your solution works for this problem. However when I pass a different json data format it give an error. is there a way to make this generic such that it can flatten any json format? example I used below json

Comment: @gabidoye Can you edit your question and post there the Json that causes the error?

Comment: I added the api request to the ticket.
import requests, json
URL='https://data.calgary.ca/resource/848s-4m4z.json'
data = json.loads(requests.get(URL).text)
data

Comment: I am looking to create a generic code that can parse any json format